# Very weird line breaking in inline code fragments

Tags: bug, markdown

I was looking at the revisions for an answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9883590/revisions/

The first revision has some weird line breaks in the (long) list of comma-separated constant-width font type names in running text, yet the source is straight-forward.

Formatted:

> The fixed-point types are `short _Fract`, `_Fract`, `long _Fract`, `long long _Fract`,
>   `unsigned short _Fract`, `unsigned _Fract`, `unsigned long _Fract`, `unsigned long long
>   _Fract`, `_Sat short _Fract`, `_Sat _Fract`, `_Sat long _Fract`, `_Sat long long _Fract`,
>   `_Sat unsigned short _Fract`, `_Sat unsigned _Fract`, `_Sat unsigned long _Fract`, `_Sat
>   unsigned long long _Fract`, `short _Accum`, `_Accum`, `long _Accum`, `long long _Accum`,
>   `unsigned short _Accum`, `unsigned _Accum`, `unsigned long _Accum`, `unsigned long long
>   _Accum`, `_Sat short _Accum`, `_Sat _Accum`, `_Sat long _Accum`, `_Sat long long _Accum`,
>   `_Sat unsigned short _Accum`, `_Sat unsigned _Accum`, `_Sat unsigned long _Accum`, `_Sat
>   unsigned long long _Accum`.

Unformatted:

```
> The fixed-point types are `short _Fract`, `_Fract`, `long _Fract`, `long long _Fract`,
`unsigned short _Fract`, `unsigned _Fract`, `unsigned long _Fract`, `unsigned long long
_Fract`, `_Sat short _Fract`, `_Sat _Fract`, `_Sat long _Fract`, `_Sat long long _Fract`,
`_Sat unsigned short _Fract`, `_Sat unsigned _Fract`, `_Sat unsigned long _Fract`, `_Sat
unsigned long long _Fract`, `short _Accum`, `_Accum`, `long _Accum`, `long long _Accum`,
`unsigned short _Accum`, `unsigned _Accum`, `unsigned long _Accum`, `unsigned long long
_Accum`, `_Sat short _Accum`, `_Sat _Accum`, `_Sat long _Accum`, `_Sat long long _Accum`,
`_Sat unsigned short _Accum`, `_Sat unsigned _Accum`, `_Sat unsigned long _Accum`, `_Sat
unsigned long long _Accum`.
```

I can fix some of the bad breaks by splitting the source and joining lines:

> The fixed-point types are `short _Fract`, `_Fract`, `long _Fract`, `long long _Fract`,
>   `unsigned short _Fract`, `unsigned _Fract`, `unsigned long _Fract`,
>   `unsigned long long _Fract`, `_Sat short _Fract`, `_Sat _Fract`, `_Sat long _Fract`, `_Sat long long _Fract`,
>   `_Sat unsigned short _Fract`, `_Sat unsigned _Fract`, `_Sat unsigned long _Fract`,
>   `_Sat unsigned long long _Fract`, `short _Accum`, `_Accum`, `long _Accum`, `long long _Accum`,
>   `unsigned short _Accum`, `unsigned _Accum`, `unsigned long _Accum`,
>   `unsigned long long _Accum`, `_Sat short _Accum`, `_Sat _Accum`, `_Sat long _Accum`, `_Sat long long _Accum`,
>   `_Sat unsigned short _Accum`, `_Sat unsigned _Accum`, `_Sat unsigned long _Accum`,
>   `_Sat unsigned long long _Accum`.

Unformatted:

```
> The fixed-point types are `short _Fract`, `_Fract`, `long _Fract`, `long long _Fract`,
`unsigned short _Fract`, `unsigned _Fract`, `unsigned long _Fract`,
> `unsigned long long _Fract`, `_Sat short _Fract`, `_Sat _Fract`, `_Sat long _Fract`, `_Sat long long _Fract`,
`_Sat unsigned short _Fract`, `_Sat unsigned _Fract`, `_Sat unsigned long _Fract`,
> `_Sat unsigned long long _Fract`, `short _Accum`, `_Accum`, `long _Accum`, `long long _Accum`,
`unsigned short _Accum`, `unsigned _Accum`, `unsigned long _Accum`,
> `unsigned long long _Accum`, `_Sat short _Accum`, `_Sat _Accum`, `_Sat long _Accum`, `_Sat long long _Accum`,
`_Sat unsigned short _Accum`, `_Sat unsigned _Accum`, `_Sat unsigned long _Accum`,
> `_Sat unsigned long long _Accum`.
```

My impression is that the number of underscores is helping confuse the issue, but I may be wrong in that.

I wouldn't want to claim this is a high-priority issue, but it is a bit peculiar.

Comment: Looking at the formatted output today, the breaks I was seeing yesterday aren't there now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underscores are not the issue -- you can replace them with `@` or even with nothing, and you still get the same result.

It seems a hard return inside code tacks `` `..` `` is interpreted as a *literal* hard return. A deduction `easily
tested` ... "And I have tested it", as Wen said. (*)

---

<sup>* *Thief of Time*, Terry Pratchett.</sup>